# Returning an output from a .C call in R

Tags: c, r, rcpp

In the documentation for the `.C` function in R [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eC-and-_002eFortran), it says that the C function itself must be of return type `void`.  I'm working on some inherited code that uses the `.C` function (rather than `.Call` or Rcpp), but I'd like to write a function that "returns" a vector of unknown size.  If I knew the size of this vector, I could allocate it in R and pass the pointer to C, whose contents can then be modified.  Given that I don't know its size, what is the way to declare it in R?  I imagine it will have this shape, but I don't know the details:

```
output <- ?????
storage.mode(a) <- "integer"
tmp <- .C("myfunc",a,output)
```

Comment: shot in the dark: `output <- list()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you do use `.Call()` instead of `.C()` -- see recent discussions on the r-devel list.  I conjecture that you will find close to no experienced R developers suggesting to use `.C()` for new projects.

Here is a simple illustration. You are by no means forced to use Rcpp, the same code can be written in the plain C API as well, albeit not as compactly:

```
R> fx <- rcpp(signature(sn="integer"), body='   // rcpp() is from inline 0.3.10
+    int size = as<int>(sn);
+    IntegerVector v(size); 
+    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) v[i] = i;
+    return(v); 
+ ') 
R> fx(3) 
[1] 0 1 2   
R> fx(7) 
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6  
R>
```

In the old `.C()` interface, you can only return atomistic C types like `*int` or `*double` and you *cannot allocate space at the C level* as you can only "mark" `SEXP` object for management by R when you can actually return `SEXP` objects -- and only `.Call()` can.

Comment: I got a compile error with that code using inline 0.3.10. After removing the comment, it did compile and run.

Comment: My bad. The code was copye and paste and _then_ was the comment added. Fixing now -- needs C++ comment syntax.